# Windows7 to Winserver2016 large file transfer timeout with error

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer, windows-server-2016

Upgraded a Windows 7 computer acting as a server to Windows Server 2016 Essentials.  Made it a Domain Controller.

Copying large (>100gig) files FROM the server to other machines works fine at around 50mb/s

Copying large files TO the server goes at around the same speed for 1 to 2 minutes, and then I get the error

"There is a problem accessing \servername\F

Make sure you are connected to the network and try again."

This can be replicated on 3 different windows 7 machines.  Prior to the win2016 upgrade, this was not an issue.